# Adb: failed to install <base>.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Full install must include a base package]

Tags: android, apk, adb, digital-signature

I'm new to the business of Android programming. I've been trying to install a debug build via ADB:

`ᐅ unzip contero-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release.apks -d apk`:

```
ᐅ tree apk 
apk
├── splits
│   ├── base-armeabi_v7a.apk
│   ├── base-hdpi.apk
│   ├── base-ldpi.apk
│   ├── base-master.apk
│   ├── base-mdpi.apk
│   ├── base-tvdpi.apk
│   ├── base-xhdpi.apk
│   ├── base-xxhdpi.apk
│   └── base-xxxhdpi.apk
└── toc.pb

ᐅ uber-apk-signer --apks apk/splits
...
Successfully processed 9 APKs and 0 errors in 3.25 seconds.

ᐅ cd apk/splits
ᐅ ls -l
 total 29744
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey 15049816 Nov 26 13:51 base-armeabi_v7a-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey 15040146 Jan  1  1981 base-armeabi_v7a.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    12716 Nov 26 13:51 base-hdpi-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey     3993 Jan  1  1981 base-hdpi.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    12716 Nov 26 13:51 base-ldpi-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey     3009 Jan  1  1981 base-ldpi.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    95165 Nov 26 13:51 base-master-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey    87298 Jan  1  1981 base-master.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    12716 Nov 26 13:51 base-mdpi-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey     3009 Jan  1  1981 base-mdpi.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    12798 Nov 26 13:51 base-tvdpi-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey     5991 Jan  1  1981 base-tvdpi.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    12717 Nov 26 13:51 base-xhdpi-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey     5186 Jan  1  1981 base-xhdpi.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    16814 Nov 26 13:51 base-xxhdpi-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey     8195 Jan  1  1981 base-xxhdpi.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexey alexey    16814 Nov 26 13:51 base-xxxhdpi-aligned-debugSigned.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alexey alexey     8195 Jan  1  1981 base-xxxhdpi.apk
```

So far it looks pretty reasonable; then:

```
ᐅ adb install -r base-armeabi_v7a-aligned-debugSigned.apk 
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install base-armeabi_v7a-aligned-debugSigned.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Full install must include a base package]
```

What do I have wrong?